# Coordinate charts are homeomorphisms with respect to the topology induced by a differentiable structure

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $ S $ be a set. Let $ \mathscr S $ be a (say, $ \mathcal C^\infty $) maximal atlas on $ S $.

That is, let $ \mathscr S $ be a collection of charts $ (U,\phi) $ where $ U\subset S $ and $ \phi\colon U\to \underline U $ is a bijection of $ U $ with an open subset of the euclidean space, such that $ S = \bigcup_{(U,\phi)\in \mathscr S}U $ and such that the usual compatibility conditions hold, and maximal among such atlases with respect to set theoretic inclusion.

Endow $ S $ with the smallest topology $ \tau_{\mathscr S} $ such that all the $ U $ are open, for all $ (U,\phi)\in \mathscr S $.

I can show that $ \tau_{\mathscr S} $ is equivalently:

1. the topology where $ A\subset S $ is open iff for every $ a\in A $ there exists a chart $ (U,\phi)\in \mathscr S $ such that $ a\in U\subset A $;
2. the topology where $ A\subset S $ is open iff $ \phi(U\cap A) $ is open in $ \mathbb R^n $ for every $ (U,\phi)\in \mathscr S $.

Now, I want to prove that all the $ \phi $ coming from charts $ (U,\phi) $ are homeomorphisms. Using 2. it's a joke to show that $ \phi^{-1} $ is continuous. On the other hand, in the last thirty minutes I have tried and retried but I couldn't manage to show that $ \phi $ is continuous.

Any hints?

Comment: There was an answer below this question but it somehow disappeared. What happened?